# Interpolation of polynome - is degree needed?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation, numerical-calculus, interpolation-theory

I'm doing my project from numerical methods in math and I'm supposed to create the following program:

> Inputs:
>
> - $n \in [0,\infty)$
> - a sequence $\Gamma_{i=0}^{n} (u_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of    x-coordinates to interpolate
> - a sequence $\Gamma_{i=0}^{n} (v_i) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ of    y-coordinates to interpolate
>
> Output:
>
> - elements of sequence $\Gamma_{i=0}^{n} (a_i)$, which are coefficients of the interpolation of a polynome $L(x)= \sum_{i=0}^{n}
>   > a_ix^i$, defines by the $(\Gamma_{i=0}^{n} (u_i), \Gamma_{i=0}^{n}
>   > (v_i) )$

but I don't understand one thing:

From what I understand, I have to calculate the Lagrange polynomial. But what is the $n$ in the inputs and how should I include it in my calculations? Really not sure about that part. The lagrange polynome should always be the lowest degree possible, right? So why is the degree $n$ included as an input? I'm rather asking here than my prof, because I'm afraid that it's a stupid question.

EDIT: I think I understand now. The number $n$ is just the number of $x-y$ coordinates. Do I understand it correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: The number $n$ is not really needed as input since you have $u_i, v_i$ given and you can just count the number of coordinates which is $n+1$.

Comment: I don't understand why you are using the $\Gamma_{i=0}^{n}(u_i)$ notation instead of just writing $u_i$. What is $\Gamma$?

Comment: From the context it seems $\Gamma$ just turns something into a tuple, but I have never seen this notation.